# creating build types in tfs 2010

Tags: build, branch

when you create a build types how do you deal with?

do you create 3 builds per each branch as (ci,gate, manual) or per branch what is suffice to.
(ex. ci- for dev branch, nightly- main branch,manual...)

in general what is good way to follow. i have found some recommendation saying that it s good to have at least 3 build types for each branch.[rules for better source control](http://www.ssw.com.au/ssw/Standards/Rules/RulesToBetterSourceControlwithTFS.aspx).

thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's really whatever meets your needs. We create 3 types per brach (Continuous, Daily, Manual)

Continuous is used to give developers immediate feedback on their checkin so we restrict which unit tests run to keep the build nice and quick. The daily build is more comprehensive as it runs overnight and can also be used to deploy in to a smoke test environment. The manual build is used for specific milestones in the project. These builds are used to create installers and pass the application over for formal testing. So it looks something like this

**Dev Branch**
- Continuous (used for dev feedback)
- Daily (used for full test runs and deployment to smoke test environment)
- Manual (Not used)

**Main Branch**
- Continuous (Used for quick check that merging activity hasn't broken the build)
- Daily (used for full test runs and deployment to smoke test environment)
- Manual (used to denote that a build will be formally handed over to testers)

**Hotfix Branch**
- Continuous (used for dev feedback)
- Daily (used for full test runs and deployment to smoke test environment)
- Manual (used to denote that a build will be formally handed over to testers)

**Release Branch**
- Continuous (Used for quick check that merging activity hasn't broken the build)
- Daily (used for full test runs and deployment to smoke test environment)
- Manual (used to denote that a build will be formally handed over to testers)

Of course your branching strategy may differ from ours.

Comment: thanks James. read in one breath. being frankly have been reading a lot of literature lately. but almost zero practice.maybe coz i don't have a real team environment to implement.at my work we facing a lot problem for being going manual. anyway here's what i continue asking since branches are just the clone of main branch what is the difference for instance between ci_dev and ci_main. is it just check-in time right?or the selection of what to build is also differs? i mean there should really solid mind what is to be build what is not,what so i m missing here.

Comment: We tend to keep the content of the build the same across branches, so the solutions / projects being built are the same. The only thing that changes between the branches is the code being built. I hope that answers your question.